# .net Maui package for mac catalyst bundle identifier does not match specified provisioning profile

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

I'm currently building a package to deliver my .net maui app for mac catalyst.
I followed this guide for publihing my outside the app store, i generate all my profiles, bundle identifier and installed them in my computer.

[Publish guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/deployment/publish-outside-app-store?view=net-maui-7.0)

But when i run on of the last commands to generate the package:
`dotnet build -f net7.0-maccatalyst -c Release`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk/16.4.7090/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1714,3): error : Project bundle identifier 'fr.myCompany.appName (explicit)' does not match specified provisioning profile 'bundleIDName' [/Users/me/Desktop/myCompany/myCompany.Maui/myCompany.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-maccatalyst]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk/16.4.7090/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1714,3): error :          [/Users/me/Desktop/badgemanager/BadgeManager.Maui/BadgeManager.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-maccatalyst]
```

I tried alot of possibilities for this bundle identifier but always the same result. I created a new blank project to test if it was my fault but luckily i get exactly the same error in the brand new project.

In hope of a clue or a solution.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution to my problems.
The bundle identifier was configured like it should but the target in the info.plist was missleading, i just deleted the line in the info.plist and just put the right target in the .csproj file.

Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle ID you enter must correspond to the Bundle identifier in the Info.plist file in your app project.

The bundle identifier for a .NET MAUI app is stored in the project file as the Application ID property:

- In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer right-click on your .NET MAUI
  app project and select Properties. Then, navigate to the MAUI Shared
  -> General tab. The Application ID field lists the bundle identifier.
- In Visual Studio for Mac, in the Solution Window, right-click on your
  .NET MAUI app project and select Properties. Then, in the Project
  Properties window, select the Build > App Info tab. The Application
  ID field lists the bundle identifier.

When the value of the Application ID field is updated, the value of the Bundle identifier in the Info.plist will be automatically updated.

You can check this document about [Create a distribution profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/deployment/publish-outside-app-store?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-distribution-profile) for more information.

Comment: I already did this step and put the exact Bundle id in the info.plist and it's still the same error every time.
I regenerated the profile and everything for testing but same result.

Comment: You can try to clean the bin and obj files. If it still shows this error, you can reinstall the visual studio.